# How exactly does this promise example work?

Tags: javascript, promise, javascript-framework

I am studying Angular 2 and I have a doubt with this code I found in a tutorial:

```
  appStatus = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('stable');
    }, 2000);
  });
```

I understood that this instruction does something like this: set the value of the **appStatus** variable to the string 'stable' after that 2 seconds are passed. Is this it?

But what exactly is a Promise? So the **appStatus** variable contains a **Promise** object reference that I think will contain the **'stable'** resolved value after that 2 seconds are passed. But what exactly is and what contains?

What is the common use case of **Promise**?

Comment: Another good source for a read 
 https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: appStatus.then((val) => console.log(val)); //would give you 'stable' after two seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*appStatus* value will not be the string '*stable*' as you think. appStatus value is here a promise object that promises you the string 'stable' (you will get it after 2 seconds). To get the value '*stable*' from the promise (you'll get it when the 2 seconds duration ends), you have to do:

```
appStatus.then((result) => { console.log(result); });
```

Comment: Ok...I know that appStatus contains a Promise object reference but...what do you exaclty menas when you says: "that promises to give you the string 'stable' after 2 seconds"? Where this 'stable' value is stored? Into a Promise object field?

Comment: There are a couple of in depth links to how promises work above, I suggest you read them. Faly has answered your question.

Comment: @AndreaNobili It's calledback once resolved. It's not stored anywhere. You receive the value inside a .then(). You callback the value yourself here resolve('stable'); you can also reject('unstable'); with would be another callback function i.e. your error receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are used in a lot of facets of JS, angular is a minor example. Long story short, Promises are `.then`able objects. If you've ever worked with, for example, xhr (`XMLHttpRequest`), you can think of the `.then(x)` to act similarly to the `xhr.onload = x`, but this construct allows for much more powerful code. These two pieces of code *act* in very much the same way:

```
// callback "format"
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', '/api/some-query');
xhr.onload = () => { console.log(xhr.response); };
xhr.send();

// promise "format"
const xhrPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET', '/api/some-query');
  // bad error handling, but proves the point
  xhr.onload = () => { resolve(xhr.response); };
  xhr.send();
});
xhrPromise.then((text) => { console.log(text); });
```

What you have up there is using the promise pattern. To make it easier to understand, here's a similar piece using the callback pattern:

```
setTimeout(() => { f('stable') }, 2000);
```

this is assuming you append this to your current code:

```
appStatus.then((status) => { f(status) });
```

How this can be a lot better may not be clear at first, but once you delve into it and discover that promises are chainable (`appStatus.then(...).then(...)`), how error handling works with `.catch` and similar, it's easy to fall in love with them

There are plenty of good reads to understand how promises work, like [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [this post by Jake Archibald](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)